# How to Display Dialog from a class extending BaseAdaper

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am trying to display a Tabbed Pager View in Dialog Box but I am unable to initialize `getSupportFragmentManager` in my Adapter Class which 
`extends BaseAdapter`. If I am using `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` then `getSupportFragmentManager` is not showing error. Here is my Code. Please guide me.

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
 ------------
 ------------
slidingListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TabDialogFragment.createBuilder(ContactListAdapter.this, getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setSubTitle("Subtitle")
                    .setTabButtonText(new CharSequence[]{"Tab1", "Tab2"})
                    .setPositiveButtonText("Ok")
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .setNeutralButtonText("Neutral")
                    .setRequestCode(REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

How can I initialize `getSupportFragmentManager()` in my Adapter Class ?

Comment: You can give callback to your activity/fragment using listener and there  u show dialog

Comment: Please let me know much more Ram. I don't have enough knowledge to use callback as you are saying.

Comment: pass OnClick listener in adapter constructor and initialize that,then while onClick using listener give callback to u'r activity/fragment

Comment: Use interface and implements in your main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a field in your adapter's class and save the `FragmentManager` like that, by passing it in the constructor of your adapter. Something like:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public ContactListAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
 ------------
 ------------
slidingListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TabDialogFragment.createBuilder(ContactListAdapter.this, mFragmentManager)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setSubTitle("Subtitle")
                    .setTabButtonText(new CharSequence[]{"Tab1", "Tab2"})
                    .setPositiveButtonText("Ok")
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .setNeutralButtonText("Neutral")
                    .setRequestCode(REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

And when creating this adapter in your activity, create it like this:

```
ContactListAdapter mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Thank you So much Vucko... You are amazing.. :)

Comment: I am trying to learn Android so I need your company to explore my knowledge.. Thank you again so much

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is to pass the FragmentManager instance to the adapter and then use that instance.

> The best approach however will be to give the burden of dialog
>   creation to the activity itself.

1. Create an interface with the method ex. showTabDialog.
2. Implement this interface in the activity and pass interface instance through "this" to the adapter.
3. Call showTabDialog method on click and build the dialog through the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

public ContactListAdapter(View.OnClickListener clickListener)
     mOnClickListener = clickListener;
}

------------
 ------------
slidingListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           mOnClickListener.onClick(view);
    });
```

And implement mOnClickListener in u'r activity/fragment and add your dialog related code in onClick.

```
public void onClick(view view){

TabDialogFragment.createBuilder(this, getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setSubTitle("Subtitle")
                    .setTabButtonText(new CharSequence[]{"Tab1", "Tab2"})
                    .setPositiveButtonText("Ok")
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .setNeutralButtonText("Neutral")
                    .setRequestCode(REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG)
                    .show();
}
```